# Session variable is undefined in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-helper

While I was trying to execute some programs on 'sessions'. I have created a project named 'leaderboard'.

Executing this leaderboard shows some 'undefined' console log. Any idea why?

Here is my code:

```
PlayerList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.leaderboard.helpers({
        'player': function() {
            return PlayerList.find()
        },

    });
    Template.leaderboard.events({
        'click .player': function() {
            var playerId = this._id;
            Session.set('selectedPalyer', playerId);
            var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
            console.log(selectedPlayer);
        }

    });
}
```

---

```
<head>
    <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
    {{> leaderboard}}
</body>

<template name="leaderboard">
     <ul>
         {{#each player}}
         <li class="player">{{name}}: {{score}}</li>
         {{/each}}
     </ul> 
</template>
```

Comment: Please post a code snippet that you think causing problems.

Comment: added  javascript and html code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `Session` key.
Just replace `Session.set('selectedPalyer', playerId);` with `Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);` and you are ready to go:

```
PlayerList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.leaderboard.helpers({
        'player': function () {
            return PlayerList.find();
        }
    });
    Template.leaderboard.events({
        'click .player': function () {
            var playerId = this._id;
            Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
            var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
            console.log(selectedPlayer);
        }
    });
}
```